# How do I use parameter with a space in a UBOOT console?

Tags: escaping, whitespace, u-boot

I am trying to use "fatload" in UBOOT.  It takes a filepath as a parameter.  I can't manage to pass one with any spaces.

Example input:

```
fatload mmc 0:1 0x70800000 /somedir/file name with spaces.txt
```

Result:

```
reading /somedir/file

** Unable to read "/somedir/file" from mmc 0:1 **
```

I have tried

> "/somedir/file name with spaces.txt"
>
> '/somedir/file name with spaces.txt'
>
> /somedir/file\ name\ with\ spaces.txt

And even

> setenv filepath /somedir/file name with spaces.txt
>
> fatload ... ${filepath}

Nothing seems to work! I considered temporarily changing the filename, but I don't know if that is possible?  Maybe it could be done with a direct write the mmc somewhere - but I don't know where that write would occur...

***UPDATE:***

I think this version of uboot just can't take spaces in any parameters!  I've included the experts from source.  Looks like I need a good work around! (unless there is a trick to exploit here?)

Here's the pertinent uboot source for running fatload/fatls.  How do I get argv[4] to contain a space?

```
/*
 * (C) Copyright 2002
 * Richard Jones, rjones@nexus-tech.net
 *
 * See file CREDITS for list of people who contributed to this
 * project.
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston,
 * MA 02111-1307 USA
 */

/*
 * Boot support
 */
#include <common.h>
#include <command.h>
#include <s_record.h>
#include <net.h>
#include <ata.h>
#include <part.h>
#include <fat.h>


int do_fat_fsload (cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp, int flag, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long size;
    unsigned long offset;
    unsigned long count;
    char buf [12];
    block_dev_desc_t *dev_desc=NULL;
    int dev=0;
    int part=1;
    char *ep;

    if (argc < 5) {
        printf ("usage: fatload <interface> <dev[:part]> <addr> <filename> [bytes]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    dev = (int)simple_strtoul (argv[2], &ep, 16);
    dev_desc=get_dev(argv[1],dev);
    if (dev_desc==NULL) {
        puts ("\n** Invalid boot device **\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (*ep) {
        if (*ep != ':') {
            puts ("\n** Invalid boot device, use `dev[:part]' **\n");
            return 1;
        }
        part = (int)simple_strtoul(++ep, NULL, 16);
    }
    if (fat_register_device(dev_desc,part)!=0) {
        printf ("\n** Unable to use %s %d:%d for fatload **\n",argv[1],dev,part);
        return 1;
    }
    offset = simple_strtoul (argv[3], NULL, 16);
    if (argc == 6)
        count = simple_strtoul (argv[5], NULL, 16);
    else
        count = 0;
    size = file_fat_read (argv[4], (unsigned char *) offset, count);

    if(size==-1) {
        printf("\n** Unable to read \"%s\" from %s %d:%d **\n",argv[4],argv[1],dev,part);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n%ld bytes read\n", size);

    sprintf(buf, "%lX", size);
    setenv("filesize", buf);

    return 0;
}


U_BOOT_CMD(
    fatload,    6,  0,  do_fat_fsload,
    "load binary file from a dos filesystem",
    "<interface> <dev[:part]>  <addr> <filename> [bytes]\n"
    "    - load binary file 'filename' from 'dev' on 'interface'\n"
    "      to address 'addr' from dos filesystem"
);

int do_fat_ls (cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp, int flag, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *filename = "/";
    int ret;
    int dev=0;
    int part=1;
    char *ep;
    block_dev_desc_t *dev_desc=NULL;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf ("usage: fatls <interface> <dev[:part]> [directory]\n");
        return (0);
    }
    dev = (int)simple_strtoul (argv[2], &ep, 16);
    dev_desc=get_dev(argv[1],dev);
    if (dev_desc==NULL) {
        puts ("\n** Invalid boot device **\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (*ep) {
        if (*ep != ':') {
            puts ("\n** Invalid boot device, use `dev[:part]' **\n");
            return 1;
        }
        part = (int)simple_strtoul(++ep, NULL, 16);
    }
    if (fat_register_device(dev_desc,part)!=0) {
        printf ("\n** Unable to use %s %d:%d for fatls **\n",argv[1],dev,part);
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc == 4)
        ret = file_fat_ls (argv[3]);
    else
        ret = file_fat_ls (filename);

    if(ret!=0)
        printf("No Fat FS detected\n");
    return (ret);
}

U_BOOT_CMD(
    fatls,  4,  1,  do_fat_ls,
    "list files in a directory (default /)",
    "<interface> <dev[:part]> [directory]\n"
    "    - list files from 'dev' on 'interface' in a 'directory'"
);

int do_fat_fsinfo (cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp, int flag, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dev=0;
    int part=1;
    char *ep;
    block_dev_desc_t *dev_desc=NULL;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("usage: fatinfo <interface> <dev[:part]>\n");
        return (0);
    }
    dev = (int)simple_strtoul (argv[2], &ep, 16);
    dev_desc=get_dev(argv[1],dev);
    if (dev_desc==NULL) {
        puts ("\n** Invalid boot device **\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (*ep) {
        if (*ep != ':') {
            puts ("\n** Invalid boot device, use `dev[:part]' **\n");
            return 1;
        }
        part = (int)simple_strtoul(++ep, NULL, 16);
    }
    if (fat_register_device(dev_desc,part)!=0) {
        printf ("\n** Unable to use %s %d:%d for fatinfo **\n",argv[1],dev,part);
        return 1;
    }
    return (file_fat_detectfs ());
}

U_BOOT_CMD(
    fatinfo,    3,  1,  do_fat_fsinfo,
    "print information about filesystem",
    "<interface> <dev[:part]>\n"
    "    - print information about filesystem from 'dev' on 'interface'"
);

#ifdef NOT_IMPLEMENTED_YET
/* find first device whose first partition is a DOS filesystem */
int find_fat_partition (void)
{
    int i, j;
    block_dev_desc_t *dev_desc;
    unsigned char *part_table;
    unsigned char buffer[ATA_BLOCKSIZE];

    for (i = 0; i < CONFIG_SYS_IDE_MAXDEVICE; i++) {
        dev_desc = ide_get_dev (i);
        if (!dev_desc) {
            debug ("couldn't get ide device!\n");
            return (-1);
        }
        if (dev_desc->part_type == PART_TYPE_DOS) {
            if (dev_desc->
                block_read (dev_desc->dev, 0, 1, (ulong *) buffer) != 1) {
                debug ("can't perform block_read!\n");
                return (-1);
            }
            part_table = &buffer[0x1be];    /* start with partition #4 */
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if ((part_table[4] == 1 ||  /* 12-bit FAT */
                     part_table[4] == 4 ||  /* 16-bit FAT */
                     part_table[4] == 6) && /* > 32Meg part */
                    part_table[0] == 0x80) {    /* bootable? */
                    curr_dev = i;
                    part_offset = part_table[11];
                    part_offset <<= 8;
                    part_offset |= part_table[10];
                    part_offset <<= 8;
                    part_offset |= part_table[9];
                    part_offset <<= 8;
                    part_offset |= part_table[8];
                    debug ("found partition start at %ld\n", part_offset);
                    return (0);
                }
                part_table += 16;
            }
        }
    }

    debug ("no valid devices found!\n");
    return (-1);
}

int
do_fat_dump (cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp, bd_t *bd, int flag, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    __u8 block[1024];
    int ret;
    int bknum;

    ret = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("needs an argument!\n");
        return (0);
    }

    bknum = simple_strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10);

    if (disk_read (0, bknum, block) != 0) {
        printf ("Error: reading block\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("FAT dump: %d\n", bknum);
    hexdump (512, block);

    return (ret);
}

int disk_read (__u32 startblock, __u32 getsize, __u8 *bufptr)
{
    ulong tot;
    block_dev_desc_t *dev_desc;

    if (curr_dev < 0) {
        if (find_fat_partition () != 0)
            return (-1);
    }

    dev_desc = ide_get_dev (curr_dev);
    if (!dev_desc) {
        debug ("couldn't get ide device\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    tot = dev_desc->block_read (0, startblock + part_offset,
                    getsize, (ulong *) bufptr);

    /* should we do this here?
       flush_cache ((ulong)buf, cnt*ide_dev_desc[device].blksz);
     */

    if (tot == getsize)
        return (0);

    debug ("unable to read from device!\n");

    return (-1);
}


static int isprint (unsigned char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 32 && ch < 127)
        return (1);

    return (0);
}


void hexdump (int cnt, unsigned char *data)
{
    int i;
    int run;
    int offset;

    offset = 0;
    while (cnt) {
        printf ("%04X : ", offset);
        if (cnt >= 16)
            run = 16;
        else
            run = cnt;
        cnt -= run;
        for (i = 0; i < run; i++)
            printf ("%02X ", (unsigned int) data[i]);
        printf (": ");
        for (i = 0; i < run; i++)
            printf ("%c", isprint (data[i]) ? data[i] : '.');
        printf ("\n");
        data = &data[16];
        offset += run;
    }
}
#endif  /* NOT_IMPLEMENTED_YET */
```

Here's the source for running uboot commands:

```
int run_command (const char *cmd, int flag)
{
    cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp;
    char cmdbuf[CONFIG_SYS_CBSIZE]; /* working copy of cmd      */
    char *token;            /* start of token in cmdbuf */
    char *sep;          /* end of token (separator) in cmdbuf */
    char finaltoken[CONFIG_SYS_CBSIZE];
    char *str = cmdbuf;
    char *argv[CONFIG_SYS_MAXARGS + 1]; /* NULL terminated  */
    int argc, inquotes;
    int repeatable = 1;
    int rc = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
    printf ("[RUN_COMMAND] cmd[%p]=\"", cmd);
    puts (cmd ? cmd : "NULL");  /* use puts - string may be loooong */
    puts ("\"\n");
#endif

    clear_ctrlc();      /* forget any previous Control C */

    if (!cmd || !*cmd) {
        return -1;  /* empty command */
    }

    if (strlen(cmd) >= CONFIG_SYS_CBSIZE) {
        puts ("## Command too long!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy (cmdbuf, cmd);

    /* Process separators and check for invalid
     * repeatable commands
     */

#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
    printf ("[PROCESS_SEPARATORS] %s\n", cmd);
#endif
    while (*str) {

        /*
         * Find separator, or string end
         * Allow simple escape of ';' by writing "\;"
         */
        for (inquotes = 0, sep = str; *sep; sep++) {
            if ((*sep=='\'') &&
                (*(sep-1) != '\\'))
                inquotes=!inquotes;

            if (!inquotes &&
                (*sep == ';') &&    /* separator        */
                ( sep != str) &&    /* past string start    */
                (*(sep-1) != '\\')) /* and NOT escaped  */
                break;
        }

        /*
         * Limit the token to data between separators
         */
        token = str;
        if (*sep) {
            str = sep + 1;  /* start of command for next pass */
            *sep = '\0';
        }
        else
            str = sep;  /* no more commands for next pass */
#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
        printf ("token: \"%s\"\n", token);
#endif

        /* find macros in this token and replace them */
        process_macros (token, finaltoken);

        /* Extract arguments */
        if ((argc = parse_line (finaltoken, argv)) == 0) {
            rc = -1;    /* no command at all */
            continue;
        }

        /* Look up command in command table */
        if ((cmdtp = find_cmd(argv[0])) == NULL) {
            printf ("Unknown command '%s' - try 'help'\n", argv[0]);
            rc = -1;    /* give up after bad command */
            continue;
        }

        /* found - check max args */
        if (argc > cmdtp->maxargs) {
            cmd_usage(cmdtp);
            rc = -1;
            continue;
        }

#if defined(CONFIG_CMD_BOOTD)
        /* avoid "bootd" recursion */
        if (cmdtp->cmd == do_bootd) {
#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
            printf ("[%s]\n", finaltoken);
#endif
            if (flag & CMD_FLAG_BOOTD) {
                puts ("'bootd' recursion detected\n");
                rc = -1;
                continue;
            } else {
                flag |= CMD_FLAG_BOOTD;
            }
        }
#endif

        /* OK - call function to do the command */
        if ((cmdtp->cmd) (cmdtp, flag, argc, argv) != 0) {
            rc = -1;
        }

        repeatable &= cmdtp->repeatable;

        /* Did the user stop this? */
        if (had_ctrlc ())
            return -1;  /* if stopped then not repeatable */
    }

    return rc ? rc : repeatable;
}

/****************************************************************************/

#if defined(CONFIG_CMD_RUN)
int do_run (cmd_tbl_t * cmdtp, int flag, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc < 2) {
        cmd_usage(cmdtp);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i=1; i<argc; ++i) {
        char *arg;

        if ((arg = getenv (argv[i])) == NULL) {
            printf ("## Error: \"%s\" not defined\n", argv[i]);
            return 1;
        }
#ifndef CONFIG_SYS_HUSH_PARSER
        if (run_command (arg, flag) == -1)
            return 1;
#else
        if (parse_string_outer(arg,
            FLAG_PARSE_SEMICOLON | FLAG_EXIT_FROM_LOOP) != 0)
            return 1;
#endif
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Here's parsing of commands arguments:

```
int parse_line (char *line, char *argv[])
{
    int nargs = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
    printf ("parse_line: \"%s\"\n", line);
#endif
    while (nargs < CONFIG_SYS_MAXARGS) {

        /* skip any white space */
        while ((*line == ' ') || (*line == '\t')) {
            ++line;
        }

        if (*line == '\0') {    /* end of line, no more args    */
            argv[nargs] = NULL;
#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
        printf ("parse_line: nargs=%d\n", nargs);
#endif
            return (nargs);
        }

        argv[nargs++] = line;   /* begin of argument string */

        /* find end of string */
        while (*line && (*line != ' ') && (*line != '\t')) {
            ++line;
        }

        if (*line == '\0') {    /* end of line, no more args    */
            argv[nargs] = NULL;
#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
        printf ("parse_line: nargs=%d\n", nargs);
#endif
            return (nargs);
        }

        *line++ = '\0';     /* terminate current arg     */
    }

    printf ("** Too many args (max. %d) **\n", CONFIG_SYS_MAXARGS);

#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
    printf ("parse_line: nargs=%d\n", nargs);
#endif
    return (nargs);
}
```

Comment: fatload mmc 0:1 0x70800000 /system/lib/egl/egl.cfg

** Invalid boot device **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I started hex editing the disk FAT, and it dawned on me as I read the short and long file name entries - how about trying fatload or fatls etc. with SHORT FILE NAMES?!  I tried that and it worked!

The trick is figuring out what the corresponding short name is under all the various conditions (since I see no way to list that directly), but I'm working out the logic.

This answer doesn't give you a cut/paste, but it will set you down the right path (bad pun!) if you have to deal with the same issue.

Comment: fatinfo mmc 1:0

** Invalid boot device **

Answer (score 0):

What version of U-Boot are you using?  With v2016.05 ("file with spaces.txt" is empty, mmc 0:3 is ext4, mmc 0:1 is FAT32 ):

```
=> load mmc 0:3 ${loadaddr} "/tmp/file with spaces.txt"
0 bytes read in 44 ms (0 Bytes/s)
=> load mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} "file with spaces.txt"
reading file with spaces.txt
0 bytes read in 5 ms (0 Bytes/s)
=> fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} "file with spaces.txt"
reading file with spaces.txt
0 bytes read in 5 ms (0 Bytes/s)
```

Comment: Version: U-Boot 2009.08-00326-g7fafaf1-dirty (11µ£ê 16 2012 - 14:26:11)

Comment: It looks like this issue must have been fixed somewhere between those versions.  I'm not looking to update that or edit its source at this point.  I'll be satisfied with just a semi-reasonable work around!

Comment: With something that old it's hard to say.  You may try globbing to see if the parser works with that.

Comment: Do you mean something like `fatload ... /tmp/*` ?

Comment: You don't know of a rename option do you?

Comment: Yes, I mean try fatload ... /tmp/file*with*spaces and no, we don't have a rename command.

Comment: This is also a problem with fatls btw.

Comment: Check my update on the question.  I think a rename is my only hope.  There must be a way.  That ought to be in the fat, no?  It's just knowing the addresses to write to I think...

Comment: If you're going to rebuild U-Boot, but not update to mainline, look in mainline for the likely change that fixed this problem in the parser.

Comment: Solved it.  Well, the gist of it. Working out the details now.  See my answer. Thanks for the help!